# How to use SuperScrollorama with iScroll

Tags: jquery, iscroll

Would like to use some SuperScrollorama scroll effects and have them maintained when viewed on ipad/iphone.
I've found this great little presentation showing that it can be done, but it does not explain it in a way that's making much sense to me.
Here's what I have found: http://markdalgleish.com/presentations/embracingtouch/

If anyone could shed some light, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: I've found an article explaining how to achieve parallax effects using stellar.js + iscroll here: http://markdalgleish.com/2012/10/mobile-parallax-with-stellar-js/
I think i'll just be using this combination for now, but if anyone has a way to get Super Scrollorama working with iScroll, I'd love to know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOC & CODE
https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

EXAMPLES
http://prinzhorn.github.com/skrollr/

This runs better that superscrollorama and much better in Android/iOS.